# TAB expanding filenames after make command in bash

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards, make, autocomplete

I'm preparing a makefile for converting org files to markdown files with the use of pandoc. Its content looks like this (note that conversion rule is just for a reference):

```
%.md: %.org 
    pandoc -t markdown -s $< -o $@ 

conversion: 
    pandoc -t markdown -s aa.org -o aa.md
```

Both rules work. For example, I can run:

```
make aa.md
```

or

```
make conversion
```

with success.
What is more, in bash I can expand:

```
make con\Tab
```

with a Tab key to have `conversion` autocompleted.
However it'd be convenient to have autocompletion also for filenames.
So I'd like to have something like this: assuming, that in the same folder there is a file named `filefortest.org` I write in a bash:

```
make ./fil\Tab
```

and voila! I have `filefortest` autocompleted. Is it possible to achieve this?

PS. I know that the functionality I'm asking for can be easily obtained with simple bash script: `pandoc -t markdown -s $1.org -o $1.md`. So the question is out of my curiosity....

Comment: is the `#!/bin/bash` line in your makefile an accident?

Comment: Indeed, it's an artifact from my previous experiments. I edited the post and removed it. However, having this line or not does not change anything, does it?

Comment: I don't know! My shell (admittedly, not a bash) should complete your examples, as far as I remember the completion script

Comment: nope, won't do it, either. Just for reference, `git clone https://gist.github.com/f059ce2fe275447c58b1a276e1409956.git makefile-testing`

Comment: Thanks. I've already installed zsh to try it out but my first attempts failed. Now I can uninstall it with a clear conscience ;)

Comment: Not going to cargo-cult you into zsh, but zsh with oh-my-zsh is *really* nice compared to a plain bash ;) zsh isn't much space, so maybe keep it around and give it a try one day.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you. I'll add it at the bottom of my very very long list of yak shaving tasks...

Comment: pet the good bovine boys and girls, they'd surely be happy to meet my endless meadows of yet-to-be- and half-shaven yaks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

The bash autocompletion looks inside the `makefile`, reads targets in it and use them for the possible choices. The only problem in this case - it reads only a clearly defined targets. The patterned ones are ignored.

So there are two ways to achieve what you want:

1. Manually define each individual file, instead of using `%.md: %.org` pattern.
2. Use `CMake` or some of its cousins which would create a detailed `makefile` for you.

Comment: Solution 1) is not what I'm looking for -- the name of the file is supposed to be a parameter, solution 2)  is yet another yak shaving for me at this moment. I suppose I'll stick to the bash script approach...